# Finding location from image

Tags: georeferencing, google-earth

if I have this google earth screenshot like this, is there a way I can match it to its location? I know for a fact that it is somewhere in Nevada. I believe it is current and not historical imagery.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any coordinate associated with the image, you can't do anything with that. Since you mentioned that the image is from a screenshot then you probably don't have this information.